# Changing the value of a variable inside a function

Tags: arrays, bash, function, variables

I am wondering how to return an array from a function in bash

```
array[0]=0
array[1]=0
array[2]=0

function change {

     array[0]=1
     array[1]=2
     array[2]=3

}
```

However this does not work (all elements of array are still 0)
thanks for help

Comment: Are you calling `change`? The global variable `array` should be modified.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to **call** the function.

```
#!/bin/bash

array[0]=0
array[1]=0
array[2]=0

function change {
     array[0]=1
     array[1]=2
     array[2]=3
}

change    # <--------------

echo "${array[@]}"
```

Result:

```
$ ./test
1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

yes they are still 0. because you didn't call your function at all.

try this:

```
array[0]=0
array[1]=0
array[2]=0

function change {

     array[0]=1
     array[1]=2
     array[2]=3

}

change
echo ${array[@]}
```